# setup centos 7 enviorment

Tags: 8, installation

I try to setup a Centos 7 enviorment in order to install Drupal 8.
I have followed a few tutorials like these ones:

http://orangeweb.com.au/installing-drupal-8-centos-7

http://www.linuxtechi.com/how-to-install-drupal-8-on-centos-7/

Every thing goes well until I try to install the drupal site.
when I try to install it, I get an error massage that Drupal requires a higher PHP version (5.5.9 or higher).

when i try to update the PHP version to 5.6 (according this tutorial). I still get the same error.

writing php -v on the terminal I see that the php version is now 5.6.
but when i upload a phpinfo(); file to the server I still see that the version is still 5.4.

why in the phpinfo I still see the 5.4 version?

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question a bit, we don't write or provide links to tutorials here as they don't suit the Q+A format. You'll probably find that your issue isn't related to Drupal, rather your apache/php configuration, so don't be too surprised if it doesn't get an answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you are running more than one PHP version on the server.

Did you remove the current (old) PHP version before adding the new one? Did you restart apache/the server after installing?

You may need to tell Apache manually to use the new php56.

check your `httpd.conf` for the `LoadModule` definition that defines it and make sure it's referencing the correct PHP installation.

Centos 7 http.conf location: `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

*Note that any changes you make here require that you restart apache. Also note that changing here has a risk of bringing down apache, so modify with caution.*